$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x+f_n(x))(\log(n+1))} \to 0$?
Let $f_n:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be  a sequence of measurable functions so that $f_n(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Is it true that
$$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x+f_n(x))(\log(n+1))} \longrightarrow 0?$$
I claim the answer is yes. The fact that $f_n(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}$ allows us
$$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x+f_n(x))(\log(n+1))} \leq \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x+1/n)(\log(n+1))}$$
$$= \frac{\log(1+1/n) - \log(1/n)}{\log(n+1)}=\frac{\log(1+1/n) + \log(n)}{\log(n+1)}$$
Now,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+1/n) + \log(n)}{\log(n+1)} = 1$$
and so we have an integrable majorant on $(0,1)$. Thus, by dominated convergence,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x+f_n(x))(\log(n+1))} = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(x+f_n(x))(\log(n+1))} \, dx = \int_0^1 0 \, dx = 0$$
Is this the proper use of the idea of the integrable majorant?

Isn't your calculation already a counterexample? Because take $f_n(x) = 1/n$ (also small error - the limit you computed is $1$ not $-1$).

You proved that the integrals are bounded in $n$. This doesn’t mean that you have an integrable majorant!

Comment: $\log(1 + 1/n) - \log(1/n) = \log \tfrac{1/n + 1}{1/n} = \log(n+1)$

No. Your assumptions are not enough. A general suggestion when checking these types of inequalities: check the extreme cases, which in this case would be $f(x) = f$, $f \to\infty$ and $f \to 1/n$. The former is no issue, but the latter is, as the arguments below show.

For example, let $f_n(x) = 1/n$. Then you have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + 1/n} \geq \frac{1}{2} \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}\log(n).
$$
Hence, in this case
$$
\frac{\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + 1/n}}{\log(n + 1)} \geq \frac{1}{2} \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)} \not \to 0.
$$
(In fact you can show that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + 1/n} = \log(1 + n)$ and so the ratio is actually equal to $1$.)

More generally suppose $f_n(x) \geq a_n > 0$ and define the ratio and integral
$$
R_n = \frac{I_n}{\log(b_n)} \quad I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + f_n(x)} \, dx,
$$
where $b_n \geq 1$ are some positive normalization constants.
Evidently you have
$$
I_n \leq 1 + \int_{a_n}^1 \frac{1}{x} = 1 + \log(1/a_n).
$$
Hence if $b_n \gg 1$ and $a_n b_n \gg 1$ as $n \to \infty$ then,
$$
R_n \leq \frac{1 + \log(1/a_n)}{\log(b_n)} \to 0. 
$$
(Note that by a similar argument you can also show that $b_n, a_n b_n \gg 1$ is necessary.)
For comparison, your choices $a_n = 1/n, b_n = n+1$ do not satisfy $a_n b_n \gg 1$.
